# How to count consecutive highlighted cells per column?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table looks like this:

[image]

The conditional formatting rule of this table is value`>0` turns green and value`<0` turns red.

How can I count the number of the consecutive green cells in each column? For example, `2` for `Mon` and `1` for `Sat`.

Comment: How are they colored?  If by conditional formatting, what is the rule that colors them?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with offset ranges:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$3:B$25,"<0",B$4:B$26,">0")+(B$3>0)
```

[image]

Comment: I am quite new to Excel programming, can you explain what the code means?

Comment: it counts every time one cell is positive and the one directly above is negative.  It also counts if the first in the column is positive and adds that to the count.

Comment: Thanks, what if the first and second cells are both positive or negative? Would this code still work?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my example that it counted correctly regardless if the first is positive or not.